# Rotate 2D Gaussian given parameters a,b and c

Tags: python

If this has been asked before, I will remove it.

I have a Gaussian function of the form:

```
def f(x,y):
  A=some number
  a=...
  b=...
  c=...
  return A*np.exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(x-0.5)*(y-0.5)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)
```

This is a Gaussian function symmetric around y=x, and I'd like to rotate it 45 degrees (counter)clockwise and get the new coefficients a,b and c. Wikipedia gives an overdetermined system of equations for the variances of x and y respectively, but it looks cumbersome. Is there a simple way to do this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation by 45 degrees, with the means (0.5,0.5) fixed, gives a’=(a-b+c)/2, b’=a-c=0 and c’=(a+b+c)/2 for a counterclockwise rotation and a’=(a+b+c)/2, b’=a-c=0 and c’=(a-b+c)/2 for a clockwise rotation.